# Html.Dropdownlist Disabled/read only

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can i manage my dropdownlist disabled / readOnly
This is my code :

```
foreach ( var item in Model.TranscriptData.Transcript.Where( s => s.TermNo == termItem && s.InsteadOfLessonNo == null ).ToList() )
{
    @Html.DropDownList("LetterGradeValue", new SelectList(grade, "Value", "LetterGrade", string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", coefficient, letterGradeTypeId, letterGrade)), "-", new { @onchange = "ChangeValues(" + counter + ");", @class = counter })
}
```

Comment: new { @class = "form-control", @disabled= "disabled" })

Comment: then problem is some where else

Comment: i use only @disabled = "disabled" in the last instance . It is working now . Thank you for help

Comment: What would be the point. Since disabled controls cant be edited and do not post back, you may as well save generating all that extra html and just display the text of the the item in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
@Html.DropDownList("LetterGradeValue", new SelectList(grade, "Value", "LetterGrade", string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", coefficient, letterGradeTypeId, letterGrade)), "-", new { @onchange = "ChangeValues(" + counter + ")",@disabled = "disabled", @class = counter })
```